# Function with array and object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array and an object and i would like a function `samePrice(arr,obj)` like this:

```
const arr = [0,1,2];
const obj = {
    0: 10,
    1: 10,
    2: 10,
    3: 12,
};

// samePrice(arr,obj) => true

const arr = [0,3];
const obj = {
    0: 10,
    1: 10,
    2: 10,
    3: 12,
};

// samePrice(arr,obj) => false
```

Here is my current function...

```
const samePrice = (arr,obj) => {
    let result = true;
  let it = obj[arr[0]];
  arr.forEach(item => {
    if (obj[item] !== it){
      result = false;
    }
  })  
  return result;
}
```

I am sure there is a better solution.

Comment: `(arr, obj) => false;` needs only a single line ... What should the function actually do?

Comment: The function compares the values of the array with the indexes of the object and returns true if all the values of the object corresponding to the array are equal @Teemu

Comment: "I have a solution with forEach but the function is 10+ lines long" - you should post that code, even if just as proof of effort (can even be in a folded snippet). As is, the question is indistinguishable from someone just getting their homework done for them.

Comment: I understand, 
but that was because I wasn't very proud of my javascript skills lol.
I edited my question with the function I had. @ASDFGerte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you're doing is checking that `every` element is the same as the first:

```js
const samePrice = (arr,obj) => arr.every(x => obj[x] == obj[arr[0]])

const arr = [0,1,2];
const obj = {
    0: 10,
    1: 10,
    2: 10,
    3: 12,
};

console.log(samePrice(arr,obj)); // => true

const arr2 = [0,3];
const obj2 = {
    0: 10,
    1: 10,
    2: 10,
    3: 12,
};

console.log(samePrice(arr2,obj2)); // => false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.every` to test if something is true for all array elements. So get the object value for the first array element, then test if every element is equal to that.

```js
function samePrice(items, prices) {
  if (items.length == 0) {
    return true;
  }
  let price = prices[items[0]];
  return items.every(item => prices[item] == price);
}

const arr1 = [0, 1, 2];
const obj1 = {
  0: 10,
  1: 10,
  2: 10,
  3: 12,
};

console.log(samePrice(arr1, obj1));

const arr2 = [0, 3];
const obj2 = {
  0: 10,
  1: 10,
  2: 10,
  3: 12,
};

console.log(samePrice(arr2, obj2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```js
function samePrice(arr, obj) {
  if(arr.length < 1)
    return false;
  i = 1;
  while(i < arr.length) {
    if(obj[arr[i]]!=obj[arr[i-1]])
      return false;
    i++;
  };
  return true;
}

var arr = [0,1,2];
var obj = {
    0: 10,
    1: 10,
    2: 10,
    3: 12,
};

console.log(samePrice(arr, obj));

var arr = [0,3];
var obj = {
    0: 10,
    1: 10,
    2: 10,
    3: 12,
};

console.log(samePrice(arr, obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could separate the first items areference proce and check the rest of the array against it.

```js
const
    samePrice = ([ref, ...a], prices) => a.every(k => prices[ref] === prices[k]);

console.log(samePrice([0, 1, 2], { 0: 10, 1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 12 })); //  true
console.log(samePrice([0, 3], { 0: 10, 1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 12 })); //    false
```